# seperate table header column th into two th

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make the below output to look like as in image with only seperating the header th into two th like the blue line
i need two headers for single td  please help,thanks.[image]

```html
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 90%;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left; 
}
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: It's unclear. You want to add that blue line, right? Or something else?

Comment: I don't uderstand your question. The output looks like the image. Please add some more details

Comment: yes i want split the header country into two th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is separator with blue border-left:**

```
th:last-child:after {
    content: 'Another';
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 90%;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left; 
}
th:last-child:after {
    content: 'Another';
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `colspan="2"` to the last `td` and add a `th`. That's it.

Read more about `colspan` on [w3schools colspan](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp).

```html
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 90%;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left; 
}
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Another</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td colspan="2">Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td colspan="2">Mexico</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 90%;
}
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left; 
}
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>This??</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td colspan="2">Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td colspan="2">Mexico</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```